# Make fan speed change permanent with aticonfig

Tags: fglrx, fancontrol

I have a Radeon HD 7950 on Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5. I have the fglrx-updates installed. The problem is that my gpu fan, upon startup, ramps up to 100% and stays that way. It's the  same way on my Windows partition, but I can manually set it there. I can manually set it to 20% fan speed with:

```
aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 20"
```

However, the problem is, that upon reboot, the manual fanspeed setting is forgotten and it defaults back to 100% fan speed. How can I make this permanent?

Note: I am only somewhat confident that 20% fan speed would be sufficient, as I will not be doing anything graphically intensive with it. I cannot be completely sure as the following:

```
aticonfig --adapter=0 --od-gettemperature
```

simply/suspiciously gives me a value of 0C.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a little ruby script which exactly does that](https://gist.github.com/chrp/6211802). Maybe you want to translate it into plain bash, though. [You can execute it on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) but my purpose was to have a continuous temperature based fan speed adjustment so I call it every 2 minutes with cron.